# CSS How to target element without a tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to target text that is not wrapped in any specific tag or wrapper.  I am pulling information from wordpress, using wordpress calls, so I won't be able to edit what I am pulling in.

The HTML/PHP looks like this:

```
<div class="content-box">
    <?= $page[0]->post_content; ?>      
</div>
```

The HTML outputs like this:

```
<div class="content-box">
    <h1>Title Here</h1>
    Here is some text I need to target
</div>
```

I need to hide (and manipulate with jQuery) the text in the content-box, though I can not add any HTML around it to wrap it.

What I'd like to do is initially hide the text and `fadeIn()` on hover.  So how do I target that text with CSS?

it feels like I need to do something like this:

```
.content-box > *:not(h1){
    display:none;
}
```

but that doesn't do it.

Comment: Wrap it in a span tag

Comment: You could use jQuery to add a span tag around it and then style that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's worth pointing out that you can hide the parent element using `visibility: hidden` and then display the `h1` element with `visibility: visible`. Unfortunately, you can't do this with the `display` property, though.

```css
.content-box {
    visibility: hidden;
}
h1 {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-box">
    <h1>Title Here</h1>
    Here is some text I need to target
</div>
```

If you want to wrap the text node with a span, you could use:

```
$('.content-box').contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrap('<span></span>');
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7noyagnw/)

Comment: yeah, it works with visibility only but not work with display property. +1.